# Why Does BackgroundWorker Throw An Exception While My Plain Thread Solution Doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

We're looking to avoid unresponsiveness on our UI for a potentially intensive database call.  I've been experimenting with different ways to reach the following scenario.

1. User invokes the functionality.
2. A thread is forked that executes the functionality.
3. The user has the option of canceling the functionality.
4. a. If the user does not cancel, the thread works with independent data and spawns some other, unrelated UI.
5. b. If the user does cancel, cancel the thread's processing and cancel any related activity (such as the SQL stored procedure we'll be calling -- irrelevant for the purposes of this question).

Being a low-level, C++ kinda guy myself, I first tried a straight Thread solution.  Then, I tried looking into .NET's BackgroundWorker solution (C#).

Here's the code that I use to simulate that potentially-intensive operation that the thread is to handle.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Simulates the processing for a query that is pretty much
    /// unresponsive after it's been invoked.
    /// </summary>
    public void SimulateSuperLongQuery ()
    {
        // Pass the time, for a very long time...
        for (int i=0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            SimulateSuperLongQuery();

        _completed = true;
    }
```

Peculiarly...

- My plain Thread solution works fine when calling that method.
- The BackgroundWorker solution **throws a StackOverflowException when calling that method**!

**Does anyone have any idea why the BackgroundWorker causes an exception?**

---

Code, in case it helps.  Here's a bit of the BackgroundWorker code.  It's straight off of the MSDN website.

```
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);

        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        // ...

    private void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        QuerySimulator query = new QuerySimulator();
        query.SimulateSuperLongQuery();
    }
```

Here's a bit of my plain vanilla code.

```
        // Fire up a thread to run a query
        QuerySimulator query = new QuerySimulator();
        Thread queryThread = new Thread(query.SimulateSuperLongQuery);
```

Comment: Is your code correct - you have `SimulateSuperLongQuery` calling itself - I'm surprised that the plain `Thread` version isn't overflowing the stack.

Comment: I'll assume you mean "isn't" for my plain Thread solution not overflowing the stack.  Yep!  I had the same suspicion; works fine.  The exception only gets thrown for the BackgroundWorker solution.  The self-calling is intended.

Comment: good spot and in the 5 minute edit window!

Comment: There is no reason that method should work no matter what it's running on. It will never exit, and it will never stop calling itself. Not only that, but the loop will never even hit i = 1 because each call simply starts a new loop and immediately calls itself, in a never ending recursive loop that will always lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: What's the terminating condition that should stop the recursion?

Comment: Okay, hold that thought.  Might've indeed been a silly oversight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing all the code it's kind of hard to tell for sure, but I'm almost certain your SimulateSuperLongQuery code will cause a StackOverflowException no matter what. It's calling itself recursively forever (or trying to, anyway).

How long does your plain Thread solution take to run? If you're not seeing an exception in that version, it may just be getting swallowed somewhere.

Comment: Ugh, I left out the query.Start() method.   Thanks for the input, everyone.  Need to wait 2 minutes before I can accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As people have already spotted, it is clear that you will run into a Stackoverflow, thread or not - just that in the single-threaded case I suspect that the CLR was able to do tail-call optimization.

If you want to simulate blocking thread, do just that: block it.

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: The sleep method would yield control back to whatever thread I forked, no?  If that's accurate, then it will not really emulate the environment for which I'm searching the best solution.

Comment: No, thread.sleep blocks the thread it is called in. I am certain it simulates well what you want to do.

Comment: I guess I'd need to know where you want to put it before being sure about that, or to have you define "simulate blocking thread".  I want to have my UI thread continue on, never sleeping, so it does not belong there.  I want my forked thread to be potentially doing endless computations/executions, so putting it there would yield control back to the UI thread.  That would give me a comfortable-looking scenario where the UI is responsive, no?

Comment: Of course, if you put the sleep on the UI thread it blocks. But you want some thread not coming back for a while, right? Thread.Sleep will do just that...

Comment: So Thread.Sleep is equivalent to a thread performing work?  I want to simulate the forked thread performing work.  If they're actually one and the same, then I will use the code.  It is smaller than what I currently have, after all.

Comment: In terms of it being busy and unfinished, thread.sleep is equivalent to the thread performing work.

Comment: @flq - That's not right at all. The thread will yield the rest of it's time slice and won't be scheduled by the OS again until after the timespan specified has elapsed. It's not a good simulation of work.